# Inheritance of overloaded + operator

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have a problem in inheriting overloaded + operator.
Let me make an example.

```
class Data{
protected:
    int data[3];
public:
    Data(){
        data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = 0;
    }

    Data operator+(const Data& other)
    {
        Data temp = *this;
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            temp.data[i] += other.data[i]
        }
        return temp;
    }
};

class DataInterited:public Data{
public:

};
/******************Main*****************/
DataInterited d1,d2,d3;
d3 = d1 + d2;  //=> This is compile error
```

This code generate compile error saying,

> no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘DataInterited’ and ‘Data’)

I think I have to implement `operator+` for `DataInherited` so that it return `DataInherited` instance. **But in this way, I cannot avoid code duplication.**

Is there any way to make `d3=d1+d2;` line correct while avoiding duplicating the `+ operator` implementation?

Comment: You access out of bounds of `data[]` in your `operator+` function

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things you need to know.

First, always implement `operator+` as a free function in terms of `operator+=`. It saves code duplication and is optimally efficient.

Second, you had no constructor in `DataInherited` that could take a `Data` as its argument. This is important because the result of `Data::operator+` is a Data, not a `DataInherited`.

corrected code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

class Data{
protected:
    int data[3];
public:
    Data(){
        data[0] = data[1] = data[2] = 0;
    }

    Data(const Data& other)
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(other.data), std::end(other.data), data);
    }

    Data& operator=(const Data& other)
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(other.data), std::end(other.data), data);
        return *this;
    }

    Data& operator+=(const Data& other)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            data[i] += other.data[i];
        }
        return *this;
    }

};

Data operator+(Data left, const Data& right)
{
    return left += right;
}

class DataInterited:public Data{
public:
    DataInterited(Data d = {})
    : Data(std::move(d))
    {}

};

using namespace std;

auto main() -> int
{
    DataInterited d1,d2,d3;
    d3 = d1 + d2;  //=> This is no longer a compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator are the same as defaults - any reason you wrote them out instead of either using `= default;`, or omitting entirely?  (By doing this you cause suppression of the implicitly generated move constructor and move-assignment operator)

Comment: Great!. Thanks Richard. BTW, can you explain more about why `+ operator` should be a free function? I tried making it a member function and it worked fine.

Comment: @m.m no good reason other than to demonstrate the use of std::copy

Comment: @jaejunlee free functions provide more flexibility. If you wanted to add a Data to some other type you'd have difficulty writing all the combinations of operator+ (each class would have to know about all others). With a free function this tight coupling is avoided

Comment: defaulted assign/construct is better than manual.  Converting Data to DataInherited sort of makes DataInherited pointless: DataInherited = Data+Data.  Why have DataInherited at all?

Comment: @Yakk agree on both counts. DataInherited is in this answer because it's part of the question, not because it's a good idea.

Comment: @richard the thing is, before adding your converting constructor, it wasn't completely pointless: it was a distinct type without conversion-to, just `+` didn't work as desired.  The converting ctor fixed `+`, but had side effects.

Comment: @Yakk , I don't understand you're saying pointless. What does **'DataInherited=Data+Data'** mean?

Comment: @JaeJunLEE If `DataInherited` is a different type than `Data`, it should behave differently.  Under this answer's proposal, a `Data` can implicitly convert to a `DataInherited`, and vice-versa.  That means you can add two `Data` objects, and assign it to a `DataInherited`, or add two `DataInherited` and assign to a `Data`.  Why have the type at all?

Answer (score -1):

Koenig operator forwarding to an `increment_by` function.

Derived classes can implement their own `increment_by` overloads if they want different behavior.

SFINAE stuff skipped, so bad types will give hard errors.

```
class Data{
public:
  template<class D, class Rhs>
  friend D operator+=(D&& lhs, Rhs&& rhs){
    increment_by(lhs,std::forward<Rhs>(rhs));
    return std::forward<D>(lhs);
  }
  template<class Lhs, class Rhs>
  friend Lhs operator+(Lhs lhs, Rhs&& rhs){
    lhs+=std::forward<Rhs>(rhs);
    return std::move(lhs);
  }
  friend void increment_by(Data& self, Data const&other){
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
      self.data[i] += other.data[i];
    }
  }
};
```

Both `+` and `+=` are template friends and hence the types passed can be derived classes.  So type isn't lost,

`increment_by` needs overiding if derived type needs new behaviour.  If not, leave it alone.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/843aee183ff2df99).

Do not leave the type needlessly.  Converting from base to derived basically throws out the point of the derived type.